# How dynamically create an object T at runtime?

Tags: java, jdbc

So I'm trying to implement some CRUD operations using just one method for every operation.
So I have this entity:

```
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {

    @Column(name = "ID", isPrimaryKey = true)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "MONEY")
    private double money;

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setMoney(double money){
        this.money = money;
    }

    public double getMoney(){
        return money;
    }
}
```

At runtime, I want to fetch a client from the database creating a query with Reflection. I create this query based on type T and the results are going in a ResultSet. Now, the question is, how do I manage to create the object T at runtime and use the setters to insert the attributes? I do not really know if this way is correct, but I want to achieve this through Reflection and using the Annotations.

```
public final Optional<T> get(long id) {

        //after fetching the class of T, I insert the class to dynamically
        //create the query based on reflection using the annotations
        Query creator = new SelectQuery(class);
        String query = creator.getQuery();
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setLong(1,id);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            //What to do here?
            while(rs.next()){
                T t = (T) classOfT.getConstructor(null).newInstance();
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            System.err.println("An error has occured while trying to get an object in get method!");
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Pass the `Class<T>` to your method.

Comment: What do you mean? I am already fetching the class as i said in code's comments and use it to create the T object after I am executine the query. I am taking the class of T with this:  Class<?> classOfT =((Class) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);